# What would my Election Candidate score be?

Tags: support, election, candidate-score

How can I find out what my election candidate score is?

For example, on Ask Ubuntu I'd like to see exactly what score I'd have out of 40.

A SEDE query would work but I'd like one nicely presented - an equivalent of flair would be really nice!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[Here's a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=1530814%2C3622940%2C1252759%2C871050%2C572%2C1234256%2C1065190%2C492405%2C616460%2C224988%2C3366929%2C465378%2C229044%2C1380752%2C100297%2C1849664%2C189134%2C542517%2C2371861%2C2581872%2C109702%2C3001736%2C1069068%2C476%2C995926%2C1952862%2C2876565%2C379693%2C1603234) - this displays the candidate scores for some of the candidates in the 6th election on Stack Overflow. You can use the site-switcher to make this work for user IDs on a different site:

> [image]

Pass it one or more user IDs for the site you've selected, and it'll display a total score and breakdown equivalent to the ones that would be shown on the nomination page.

[Here's your score for Ask Ubuntu.](https://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=186134)

Keep in mind that this is based on data which is updated every Sunday, so it will be out of date to a certain degree.