# I would like to see my mod candidate score, preferrably on my user page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, candidate-score

### Request

I know that [there's a SEDE query to find out my candidate score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253781/239016), but I would like it to be a standard feature on the user page.

### Rationale

The candidate score is more to me than just, well, the candidate score.
It represents how active and involved a user is. It represents *how good a user* one is.

Would it be possible to show the candidate score as a metric on the user page? The element already exists, as it is shown for mod candidates, so could that same element be shown on one's user page?
Like a comment reads, this could be a privilege to be earned with a decent amount of rep (since every k of rep is 1 point of the score, up to half of the total score, it would be a depressingly low score any way).

Comment: I think it would be interesting to have a metric other than just reputation, but I strongly disagree that candidate score measures how good a user someone is. It's heavily weighted toward users that have been here a long time, which is important for moderators, but not a good measure for community members. A metric for how good a user is would be more dynamic and not score users who are no longer active better than users currently participating on a site.

Comment: @ColleenV I wholeheartedly agree. Stack Exchange seems to favour user age over user activity, not just here.